# Magento Products on Homepage in combination with Flat Catalog not working

Tags: magento-1.6, magento

I have some problems with products showing on the homepage and flat catalog.

With the flat catalog option off:

In the CMS I have created a static block with the contents:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="18" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

In my templates I have defined a call to this static block. Because I want the products on a specific spot I use this way and it works perfectly.

When I switch on flat catalog to yes, re-index and clear caches:

The homepage no longer shows the products in the category but shows "There are no products matching the selection.". I have been doing some simple debugging and it looks like the `list.phtml` page gets an empty productcollection.

Any tips on how to solve this ?

Comment: You can look for difference betwen after and before you change the code, on phtml you do echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); and see what is wrong

Comment: Thanks. The query with flat catalog ON is selecting the wrong cat_index.category_id on the inner join. The right category_id = 18 but it is using 2 for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I search a way to figure this and found something like that:

```
  <reference name="content">
 <block type="catalog/product_list" name="new-arrival-products" alias="arrival_products" template="catalog/product/new_arrival.phtml">
....
    <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>6</value></action>
 </block>
```

Try this code, fi not working probably you'll need change the code from phtml to renderize this collection.

To use new category on you static block, you must go to Catalog -> Manage Category -> Click on your category, on your category you select Display Setting tab, and select your block on CMS Block.

Comment: I use a static block not a cms page, I cannot set these settings in a static block.?

Comment: With static block you'r doing right. but maybe magento can't use this param in collection, you need change the core code to use your param.

Comment: Ok, i found a way to solve what you need. Look the answer i've edited.

Comment: Not working. It still renders the wrong category_id and returns emtpy

Comment: Its becouse your category block don't use this param category_id to render the collection, you should go to view.phtml and there you load the category by $this->getCategoryId(); and set to $_category should do the job.

Comment: It sounds all complicated for something that looks simple. Maybe easier to not use flat catalog? However I would like to understand why the behavior is different.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The category I wanted on the homepage (18) was not in the root category (2) of my shop. I moved cat 18 under cat 2 and the issue was solved.

It looks like Magento 1.6 does work with flat catalogs and categories outside of your root category